# Sending JSON to drupal server gives "Invalid Method" in Objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, drupal

I am writing an iPhone app and trying to send a POST request to drupal server with a JSON object but it always returns me

> {"#error":true,"#data":"Invalid method

I tried following:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxx/services/json"]];

[urlReq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[urlReq setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *stringBody = @"{data:{\"method\":\"views.get\",\"view_name\":\"words\",\"args\":[\"wod_businessspotlight\"],\"limit\":365}}";

NSData *dataBody = [stringBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[urlReq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [dataBody length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[urlReq setHTTPBody:dataBody];

NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlReq delegate:self];

[con start];
```

I have seen a similar problem at [iPhone + Drupal + JSON RPC Server problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596324/iphone-drupal-json-rpc-server-problem) but it doesn't mention Where can I find SBJSON class and JSONFragment method.

Also I have downloaded https://github.com/stig/json-framework/ but couldn't find JSONFragment method anywhere.**

Please help me out of this. 
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still running into issues with this, I propose to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which makes the problem trivial.

For your particular example of views.get, you do have a couple required arguments that you need to send: a hash, a domain name, a domain timestamp, a nonce and a view name. You then have several other optional parameters.

I assume you are using services module, however if you are on version 3.x, you could use the DIOS (drupal-ios-sdk), I've heard many good things about it. However if you're on 2.x or just want to do it yourself, here's a working example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:endpoint]; //endpoint:domain.com/services/json

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"view.get" forKey:@"method"];
[request setPostValue:[hash JSONString] forKey:@"hash"];
[request setPostValue:[domain JSONString] forKey:@"domain_name"];
[request setPostValue:timestamp forKey:@"domain_time_stamp"];
[request setPostValue:[nonce JSONString] forKey:@"nonce"];
[request setPostValue:[viewName JSONString] forKey:@"view_name"];
[request startSynchronous];

NSDictionary *deserializedData = 
           [[[[request responseData] objectFromJSONData] JSONString]
                                     objectFromJSONString];
NSArray *resultList = [deserializedData objectForKey:@"data"];
```

As you can see, only the datatypes other that int, with the exception of the method name, need to be JSON encoded. I don't know if that is a best practice but it has worked for me so far. (:
As a side note, I am using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) because its awesomly simple, only two files, and according to the main author, it beats all others in terms of efficiency...

If you want any details on how to do the hashing, please let me know. It was a pain to create but I found nice little efficient ways to do it, I think.

Comment: Btw this method is especially good if you want to still use the API key auth that services 2 used...